# Embed a bash shell script in an AppleScriptObjC application with Xcode

Tags: xcode, bash, applescript, applescript-objc

I have attempted to follow the instructions on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362914/is-there-a-way-to-package-bash-shell-scripts-with-applescriptobjc-app-on-macosx) but I am falling short of understanding how some of the posters instructions work.

I want to be able to package the app with a prewritten bash script and then execute it, but don't follow from **Step 4** onwards.

---

Post writes:

*4. Also in your AppleScriptObjC script, add the following where appropriate:*

```
    property pathToResources : "NSString"  -- works if added before script command
```

*5. Where appropriate, also add the following in your AppleScriptObjC script:*

```
    set yourScript to pathToResources & "/yourScriptFile.sh" 
    -- gives the complete unix path
    -- if needed, you can convert this to the Apple style path:
    set yourScriptPath to (((yourScript as text) as POSIX file) as alias)`
```

*6. As an aside, you could then open the file for read using*

```
    tell application "Finder"
        open yourScriptPath
    end tell
```

---

Questions:

1. Where do I add the line:

   ```
   property pathToResources : "NSString"
   ```
2. Do I add which of the following, and where?

   ```
   set yourScript to pathToResources & "/yourScriptFile.sh"
   ```

   OR

   ```
   set yourScriptPath to (((yourScript as text) as POSIX file) as alias)
   ```
3. How is it possible to execute the script itself? The mention `As an aside, you could then open the file for read using` only covers the Apple style path, it does not cover using the aforementioned style.

---

Can anyone shed a bit more light on this for me, or post a static copy of a `AppDelegate.applescript` file that shows how the original poster required the base code to be used? I have tried his method and looked across the internet for the past 3 weeks to no avail. I don't want to have to convert all my code for specific tools from bash scripts into AppleScript, as this would take a lot of work.

I only need to know how to reference to the script file (for example `myBashScript.sh`) in my app, which would reside in the application and be included by Xcode at time of compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I ended up bringing all the information together and now have a solution.*

---

This takes into consideration the following facts:

**firstScript** = variable name that points to a script called scriptNumberOne.sh
**scriptNumberOne.sh** = the script that I have embedded into my application to run
**ButtonHandlerRunScript_** = the name of the [Received Action](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/06/creating-outlets-and-actions-via-drag-and-drop-in-xcode-4/) in Xcode
**pathToResources** = variable that points to the internal Resources folder of my application, regardless of it's current location

Using this information, below is a copy of a vanilla `AppDelegate.applescript` in my AppleScriptObjC Xcode project:

```
script AppDelegate
property parent : class "NSObject"
property pathToResources : "NSString"

on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
    set pathToResources to (current application's class "NSBundle"'s mainBundle()'s resourcePath()) as string
end applicationWillFinishLaunching_

on ButtonHandlerRunScript_(sender)
    set firstScript to pathToResources & "/scriptNumberOne.sh"
    do shell script firstScript
end ButtonHandlerRunScript_

on applicationShouldTerminate_(sender)
    -- Insert code here to do any housekeeping before your application quits 
    return current application's NSTerminateNow
end applicationShouldTerminate_

end script
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the command `path to resource <specifiedResource>`.

See Standard Additions, `path to resource`.

You could set it by `set myVariableName to path to resource "myBashScript.sh"` or just use the command instead of your property so it points always to the right place (a user could move your app while running... lol).

---

ADDITION:

I did it that way in my AppleScript-Application:

```
on run_scriptfile(this_scriptfile)
    try
        set the script_file to path to resource this_scriptfile
        return (run script script_file)
    end try
    return false
end run_scriptfile
```

Whenever I want to run a script that is bundled within my app I do this:

```
if my run_scriptfile("TestScript.scpt") is false then error number -128
```

`run_scriptfile(this_scriptfile)` returns `true` when everything worked.

Comment: Can you show me an example of this?

Here is a pastebin for a blank app: http://pastebin.com/6BZr5e8L

Comment: Open AppleScript Editor, press shift-command-l to see the Library, open "Standard Additions", search for "path to resource". Read that info.

Comment: What do you mean by `or just use the command instead of your property` ?

Comment: BTW: I used AppleScript Editor to create my app, so may be it's different here. But you will see if it works.